# captcha code for the first time wrong you have to add the code twice

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax

I have a captcha control, when write code and check it it always be wrong if I write it correctly , then form the second time it works fine. 
what may be the problem in that 
that is the captcha

```
<td id="Td6" runat="server" align="center" class="style4">
    <MSCapatchaControl:CaptchaControl ID="Capatcha" 
                                      runat="server" 
                                      BackColor="#CC3300" 
                                      CaptchaBackgroundNoise="Extreme" 
                                      CaptchaChars="ACDEFGHJKLNPQRTUVXYZ2346789" 
                                      CaptchaHeight="40" 
                                      CaptchaMaxTimeout="240" 
                                      CaptchaMinTimeout="5" 
                                      CaptchaWidth="130" 
                                      FontColor="White" 
                                      ForeColor="White" 
                                      LineColor="Black" 
                                      NoiseColor="Black" />
</td>
<td id="Td7" runat="server" colspan="3">
    <asp:TextBox ID="registerCaptchText" 
                 runat="server" MaxLength="6" Width="135px">
    </asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" 
                                runat="server" 
                                ControlToValidate="registerCaptchText"  
                                Display="None" 
                                ErrorMessage="Enter the capatcha">
    </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <font style="font-size:12px; font-family:trebuchet; color: rgb(51, 51, 51);">
        <div class="important">*</div>
        Please enter the text you see in the image. 
    </font>
</td>
```

and that is the function test it

```
Capatcha.ValidateCaptcha(registerCaptchText.Text);
            bool capatchaValid = Capatcha.UserValidated;
```

Comment: Is this what you only have in your page?

Comment: no it is a form and that is an element on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I have solved this problem by taken captcha field in update panel.
Thanks Every one for your value able time.